# animation-fill-mode - Cant set to foward

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm animating a page and it ends with a image transition that covers the entire page. Once it gets to that point I want the animation to stop on the last frame and leave the iamge over the entire page. I tried using

animation-fill-mode: forward;

but that isn't correct according to Webstorm, and it does nothing in JsFiddle.
Here is what I have so far.

```
//jsfiddle.net/wundersoy/kkk53jx6/1/embed/"></script>
```

Comment: There is a reason SO requires you to post code with a jsfiddle link...

Comment: Can anyone help? aniamtion-fill-mode: forwards; doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is `animation-fill-mode: forwards` not forward.

The property is also not supported in Internet Explorer 9 or earlier

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed that.

Comment: The animation still doesn't stay on the last frame when I used "animation-fill-mode: fowards;"
Why would this be?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the element position:absolution.

Comment: This answer is not explanatory at all, nor are you sure that it solves the problem.

Comment: You can see is the element display:inline.If it's ture,you can set the element display:inline-block or block.

Comment: Please _edit_ your answer to enhance it, don't use comments for that! Have a look at [answer]!